# C++ login panel to view cout

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int choice,num1,num2,num3,num4,result;

    cout<<"NOTE:PASSWORD IS HIHGLY ENCYRPTED BETWEEN EACH 2 NUMBERS a + Sign!!!!"<<endl;
    cout<<"Choose where you want to go:"<<endl;
    cout<<"1-Wifi password list"<<endl;
    cout<<"2-Facebook Password & Email"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    cout<<"Please Enter the password to continue:"<<endl;
    cin>>num1>>num2>>num3>>num4;

    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1: if (result==100)
            {
                cout<<"!!!!!Congratz you are Proffesional Cracker!!!!!"<<endl;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
        result=num1+num2+num3+num4
            cout<<"The sum of the Numbers aren't equal to the encyrpted number! try again"<<endl;
            break
            }
    }



    return 0;
}
```

i am making this project that if he choose case 1: ...... the "IF" show if result==100 then to cout<<"You are proffesinal cracker"<

but after compiling errors displayed in output

> 1>------ Build started: Project: login, Configuration: Debug Win32
>   ------ 1>  stdafx.cpp 1>  login.cpp 1>c:\users\mycomm\desktop\gallery\c++\login\login\login.cpp(12): error
>   C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\mycomm\desktop\gallery\c++\login\login\login.cpp(12): error
>   C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\mycomm\desktop\gallery\c++\login\login\login.cpp(13): error
>   C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\mycomm\desktop\gallery\c++\login\login\login.cpp(13): error
>   C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\mycomm\desktop\gallery\c++\login\login\login.cpp(14): error
>   C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\mycomm\desktop\gallery\c++\login\login\login.cpp(14): error
>   C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\mycomm\desktop\gallery\c++\login\login\login.cpp(15): error
>   C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\mycomm\desktop\gallery\c++\login\login\login.cpp(15): error
>   C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\mycomm\desktop\gallery\c++\login\login\login.cpp(16): error
>   C2065: 'cin' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\mycomm\desktop\gallery\c++\login\login\login.cpp(17): error
>   C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\mycomm\desktop\gallery\c++\login\login\login.cpp(17): error
>   C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\mycomm\desktop\gallery\c++\login\login\login.cpp(18): error
>   C2065: 'cin' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\mycomm\desktop\gallery\c++\login\login\login.cpp(24): error
>   C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\mycomm\desktop\gallery\c++\login\login\login.cpp(24): error
>   C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\mycomm\desktop\gallery\c++\login\login\login.cpp(30): error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cout'
>   1>c:\users\mycomm\desktop\gallery\c++\login\login\login.cpp(30): error
>   C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\mycomm\desktop\gallery\c++\login\login\login.cpp(30): error
>   C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\mycomm\desktop\gallery\c++\login\login\login.cpp(32): error
>   C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

please review my code and help

Comment: For starters, your code is missing semi-colons in your `else` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler does not recognise cout in this context.
You should refer the scope of cout with the **scope operator ::**

cout is part of the `std` namespace.

So wherever you have `cout`, substitute it with `std::cout`.
The same is part with endl -> std::endl. The same applies to `cin` -> `std::cin`. Alternatively use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`.

**Just for further knowledge:**

You could add `using namespace std;` in the top of your code. But, it is not normally suggested because of the best answer provided in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

**And some advice:**

Your switch statement is redundant, since you only evaluate if a value is ONE SINGLE option. You can change it with a normal if statement and then nest your existing if statement inside. Check [switch statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) documentation to see when it is more appropriate to use it.